# proving inequality in Riemann zeta function

Tags: cv.complex-variables, sequences-and-series, limits-and-convergence, riemann-zeta-function

Recently I have made some interesting observations on the limit $$\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}{\sum_{n=1}^{k}{\dfrac{(-1)^{n-1}\biggl( \cos \left(\beta\ln(n)\right)\biggr)}{n^{\alpha}}}}. $$ When this limit exist denoteits convergence point by $\zeta$.  If we define $f_k$ to be the partial sums of this series:

$$f_k(\alpha,\beta):= \sum_{n=1}^{k}{\dfrac{(-1)^{n-1}\biggl( \cos \left(\beta\ln(n)\right)\biggr)}{n^{\alpha}}} $$ I want to prove that $$f_{2k}(\alpha,\beta)\le \zeta \le f_{2k+1}(\alpha,\beta)$$ for all values k. One approach is to prove them separately. First show $\zeta-f_{2k}(\alpha,\beta)\ge 0$ and then $f_{2k+1}(\alpha,\beta) - \zeta \le 0$.

From this we can easily obtain small bounds on the actual value of the zeta function and hopefully show that the there is only one value of $\alpha$ such that both the limits $$\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}{\sum_{n=1}^{k}{\dfrac{(-1)^{n-1}\biggl( \cos \left(\beta\ln(n)\right)\biggr)}{n^{\alpha}}}}$$ and $$\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}{\sum_{n=1}^{k}{\dfrac{(-1)^{n-1}\biggl( \sin\left(\beta\ln(n)\right)\biggr)}{n^{\alpha}}}}$$ are both simultaneously zero. We should be able to bound zeta by the first few terms.

Comment: Please spell Riemann's name correctly.

Comment: hahah sure sure

Comment: Note $$\sum_{n=1}^{k}{\dfrac{(-1)^{n-1}\biggl( \cos \left(\beta\ln(n)\right)\biggr)}{n^{\alpha}}}$$ does not depend on $n$, yet you call it $f_k(n)$.  Perhaps it should be something like $f_k(\alpha,\beta)$.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar yes of course oops

Comment: For some $n$ you could have $\cos(\beta\ln (2n+1)) < 0$ which will violate the inequality $f_{2n} \le f_{2n+1}$ .

Comment: to show violation you need to show all terms add up and violate it

Comment: "When this limit exist denoteits convergence point by ."  I have no idea what you mean by "its convergence point". Also: Kindly do elementary copy editing of your post before inflicting it on others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inequality you want to prove is false. For example,
$$f_5(1/2,1)=0.6096\dots,$$
while
$$\lim_{k\to\infty}f_k(1/2,1)=0.6398\dots$$

Comment: I will have to check your calculations. see this post for more numerical evidence.  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/441121/convergence-and-roots-of-alternating-periodic-infinite-series

Comment: @MrPie Note also that Gerald Edgar was right in his comment. If $\cos(\beta\ln (2k+1))$ is negative, then $f_{2k+1}(\alpha,\beta)<f_{2k}(\alpha,\beta)$ for any $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: maybe the inequality just flips in the other situations.

Comment: It seems to satisy some type of wave behavior that we can study. Find out how fast these waves are decreasing or increasing and try to capture an appropriate value of zeta from it. It doesnt seem far off from its first few points. Its definitely oscillating around its convergence point.

Comment: @The point is that $f_{2k+1}(\alpha,\beta)-f_{2k}(\alpha,\beta)$ changes sign infinitely often for most $\beta$'s.

Comment: my observation suggest that zeta is not far away from this difference.

Comment: "It is definitely oscillating around its convergence point" Yes, but that's not surprising, and probably easy to show.

Comment: Well, the limit (when it exists) is just the real part of $(1-2^{1-s})\zeta(s)$ for $s=\alpha+i\beta$, and that's well-known.

Comment: yes but we should be able to bound this easily with the first few terms then maybe if it keeps bouncing around it

Comment: At any rate, I answered your question. If you have an other question, please open a new page for it. Note also that lengthy discussions are discouraged here (MO is not a forum). I finish the discussion here.